# DCC coupling of N-hydroxysuccinimide and 2,2-dimethoxyacetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecular-structure, nmr-spectroscopy, molecules

I am forming *N*-hydroxysuccinimide ester (**1**) by DCC coupling with *N*-hydroxysuccinimide and 2,2-dimethoxyacetic acid using distilled THF as solvent.

[image: 2,5‐dioxopyrrolidin‐1‐yl 2,2‐dimethoxyacetate]

What I see on $\ce{^1H}$-NMR is three major singlets:
$\delta~\pu{4.840 ppm}~(1\ce{H}),$ $\delta~\pu{3.432 ppm}~(7.26\ce{H}),$ $\delta ~\pu{2.731 ppm}~(6.36\ce{H})$ and some impurities.

While the chemical shifts are well-aligned with theoretical predictions (in my opinion), integration ratios do not quite make sense. I wish I could purify it to have a clearer NMR spectrum and see whether I actually have the desired product, but I don't think my ester will stay stable in silica in column chromatography. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe take or get an NMR of the reagents and theoretical side products and see if there can be any overlap with the signals you see. I'm not sure I understand what your doubt is, though. NMR integration is not always very precise, especially for acidic protons.

Comment: What is your next reaction with this product?

Comment: @user6376297 I have already taken the NMR of 2,2-Dimethoxy Acetic acid: 

$\delta \: \pu{4.867 ppm}$ (1H) and $\delta \: \pu{3.4615 ppm}$ (6.6H)

(c.f. $\delta \: \pu{4.840 ppm}$ (1H) and $\delta \: \pu{3.432 ppm}$ (7.26H) in my product NMR)

Not sure whether I can argue that peaks have 'shifted' in the product NMR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If peaks for "some impurities" are appear around $\delta \: \pu{1.8 ppm}$, I assume you have residual THF in your crude product. The other multiplet of THF is probably burried under $\delta \: \pu{3.43 ppm}$ resonance. That would confirmed by your impurity integration, which should be equal to 1H unit equivalence. If I'm right, your 6.36H unit equivalence is actually overlap one of $\ce{CH3}$-resonance and one of $\ce{CH2}$-resonance.

On the other hand, the two resonances at $\delta \: \pu{3.43 ppm}$ and $\delta \: \pu{2.73 ppm}$ would very well be representing two $\ce{CH3}$-groups and (two $\ce{CH2}$-groups + part of THF impurity), respectively, as well.

Comment: Thanks. but I have thoroughly vacuum dried my product and there is no peak at δ1.8 ppm.